# Creating unique ptrs from a raw ptr of another unique ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

What happens when I create a unique pointer using the raw pointer of another unique pointer? In the example below, what would happen when create second class is called? I thought that first_obj_ would give up ownership when second_obj_ is created, but first_obj_ doesn't give up ownership when get is called.

```
class SecondClass {
     SecondClass(Object* obj) : second_obj_(obj) {}
     .....
     private:
          std::unique_ptr<Obj> second_obj_;
}

class FirstClass {
     FirstClass() {
          std::unique_ptr<Obj> first_obj_ = std::make_unique<Obj>();
      }
      std::unique_ptr<SecondClass> CreateSecondClass() {
           std::make_unique<Obj>(first_obj_.get());      
       }
     .....
     private:
          std::unique_ptr<Obj> first_obj_;
          SecondClass second_class;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to `return` in `CreateSecondClass`.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Obj> first_obj_` shadows `this->first_obj_`. Your `FirstClass` constructor doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: It looks like your entire `class`s are `private`. From the series of mistakes I've noticed, this doesn't appear to be real code you've tried. Before asking about code here, it's important to test it yourself first. It helps us better answer your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`release()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) if you want to give up ownership.

`std::unique_ptr` cannot know what you will do with the pointer extracted with `get()` and in particular it cannot know that you decided to give it to another `std::unique_ptr`.

If two `std::shared_ptr`s will store the same pointer, you will get double `delete` of the object, which is Undefined Behaviour.

---

However, if you want to pass ownership from one `std::unique_ptr` to another, you should probably use move semantics instead:

```
class Obj {};

struct SecondClass {
    SecondClass(std::unique_ptr<Obj>&& obj) : second_obj_(std::move(obj)) {}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Obj> second_obj_;
};

struct FirstClass {
    FirstClass() {
        first_obj_ = std::make_unique<Obj>();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<SecondClass> CreateSecondClass() {
        return std::make_unique<SecondClass>(std::move(first_obj_));  
        //note that first_obj_ points to nullptr now. Only SecondClass owns the Obj.
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Obj> first_obj_;
};
```

Comment: If you `release` with the intention of passing the pointer to another `unique_ptr`, you should just use move semantics instead.

Answer (score 2):

> What happens when I create a unique pointer using the raw pointer of another unique pointer?

BAD THINGS CAN HAPPEN!

You end up with 2 `unique_ptr` objects that both think they are the exclusive owner of the raw pointer, and so both objects will try to manage and ultimately free the owned memory.  To avoid that, you have to pass ownership from one `unique_ptr` to the other, or else give at least one of the `unique_ptr`s a custom `deleter` that does not free the memory (in which case, you shouldn't be using 2 `unique_ptr` objects to begin with).

> In the example below, what would happen when create second class is called?

Both `first_obj_` and `second_obj_` end up holding pointers to the same `Object` in memory, and both of them will try to `delete` it.

> I thought that `first_obj_` would give up ownership when `second_obj_` is created

No, because `unique_ptr::get()` simply returns a copy of the raw pointer, it does not release ownership of the pointer.  If you want that, use `unique_ptr::release()` instead:

```
class SecondClass {
public:
    SecondClass(Object* obj) : second_obj_(obj) {}
    ...
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Object> second_obj_;
};

class FirstClass {
public:
    FirstClass() : first_obj_(std::make_unique<Object>()) {}

    std::unique_ptr<SecondClass> CreateSecondClass() {
        return std::make_unique<SecondClass>(first_obj_.release());
    }
    ...
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Object> first_obj_;
};
```

Otherwise, you can simply `std::move` one `unique_ptr` into the other:

```
class SecondClass {
public:
    SecondClass(std::unique_ptr<Object> obj) : second_obj_(std::move(obj)) {}
    ...
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Object> second_obj_;
};

class FirstClass {
public:
    FirstClass() : first_obj_(std::make_unique<Object>()) {}

    std::unique_ptr<SecondClass> CreateSecondClass() {
        return std::make_unique<SecondClass>(std::move(first_obj_));
    }
    ...
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Object> first_obj_;
};
```

If you truly want `FirstClass` and `SecondClass` to share the same pointer, then use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr`:

```
class SecondClass {
public:
    SecondClass(std::shared_ptr<Object> obj) : second_obj_(obj) {}
    ...
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Object> second_obj_;
};

class FirstClass {
public:
    FirstClass() : first_obj_(std::make_shared<Object>()) {}

    std::unique_ptr<SecondClass> CreateSecondClass() {
        return std::make_unique<SecondClass>(first_obj_);
    }
    ...
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Object> first_obj_;
};
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - "*if you have a `unique_ptr` with a do nothing deleter, you probably want a raw pointer anyway*" - yes, that is why I said "in which case, you shouldn't be using 2 `unique_ptr` objects to begin with".